# Possible bug with Process Builder, Apex Unit Tests and API Version

Tags: apex, process-builder, api-version

I ran into this issue last week during a deployment and submitted as a potential bug. Not surprising, Salesforce Support pushed back heavily saying that this is a feature of the application, not a bug. I’m curious what others think.

Background:

- The Production org had older unit test classes with API versions ranging from 18 all the way up to 35. Prior to deployment, all unit tests in Production completed successfully with more than adequate code coverage.
- My client built a set of Processes in Process Builder that referenced the Opportunity.ContractId field - a field not visible until API version 31. These were deployed into Production successfully. Subsequent runs of all unit tests (via Test Execution) completed successfully with zero failures.
- After their deployment completed, I attempted to deploy Apex changes - primarily new Apex Classes and Triggers to support their new workflow. Even though all Unit Tests ran in both the Sandbox and Production, my change set failed validation with 6 unit test failures - all on older Unit Test classes that were not modified, being deployed, or were even related to the current set of changes. Running all Unit Tests independent of deployment still worked fine.
- The basic error across all tests was the following:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, The record couldn’t be saved because it
>   failed to trigger a flow. unable to find field dataType for complex
>   reference: myVariable_current.ContractIdNotFound, element:
>   interaction.definition.mdapi.FlowVariable@29fd8c4b, dataType: null
>   Contact your administrator for help.: []

- Eventually I noticed a pattern in the failures - all were older Unit Test classes with API versions prior to v31. Technically that should not have mattered, but out of curiosity I changed the API versions on all of these classes to 35 and added to my change set. Sure enough that solved the issue.

I see two problems that make me feel this is a bug:

1. Process Builder is executing at the API-level context of the "last" bit of Apex that caused it to execute. So, if the insert was taking place in a Unit Test at API v24, Process Builder will run at API v24 - meaning it has no access to the Opportunity.ContractId field. (I don't see this with workflow rules).
2. The above Unit Test failures only occur during Deployment (Change Set or Ant), not when run tests are run independently.

Is this truly a bug, or a “feature” as support suggests?

Cross posted from https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00002g0SEU

Comment: I think its a 'feature' as this was in visual flow as well. If you need such a field visible across multiple api versions consider copying the standard field into a custom field via formula/apex/workflow.